# Lógica de Vetores Aninhados - C++

Tags: c++, lógica, array

Tenho um problema com o seguinte enunciado:

Dado um vetor A com n números reais, obter um outro vetor B, também com n números reais, da seguinte forma:

B[1] = 2*A[1]

B[2] = 3*A[1] + 2*A[2]

B[3] = 4*A[1] + 3*A[2] + 2*A[3]

(...e assim por diante)

Fiz o programa, porém minha lógica está errada e não consigo identificar o erro. Alguém pode me ajudar? Segue o código que escrevi.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int tamanho;

    cout << "Qual o tamanho do vetor?  ";
    cin >> tamanho;

    float vetorA[tamanho], vetorB[tamanho];

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){  
        cout<< "Digite o numero :";     
        cin >> vetorA[i];
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){
        for(int j = 2; j <= tamanho + 1; j++){
            vetorB[i] += j * vetorA[i];
        }       
    }   


    int i = 0;

    while(i < tamanho){
        cout << "\nA["<< i << "] = " << vetorA[i] << "\t B[" << i << "] = " << vetorB[i]; 
        i++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Observação: O programa roda sem erros de compilação. O erro está na lógica!

Comment: Não precisa colocar `RESOLVIDO`, isso é indicado de outra forma, com uma resposta aceita. [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91) e [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Obrigada pela dica!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talvez, ter pensado em uma **“fórmula”** ajudaria para que chegasse ao resultado correto mais *rapidamente*.

### B[n] = (n+1) * A[1] + n * A[2] + (n-1) * A[3] +...+ 3 * A[n-1] + 2 * A[n]

O erro era realmente apenas na lógica. Analisando o enunciado com atenção podemos perceber alguns padrões.

[image: Explicação gráfica]

É perceptível que você reconheceu o padrão observando seu código.

```
for(int i = 1; i <= tamanho; i++){
    aux = i + 1;
    for(int j = aux, k = 1; k <= i; j--, k++){
        vetorB[i-1] += j * vetorA[k-1];
    }       
}
```

O ***for*** mais externo, tem como condição de parada, o tamanho do vetor. Ao armazenar o valor de **i** em uma variável auxiliar acrescida de uma unidade, cobre uma das condições para que o resultado certo seja obtido.
No segundo ***for***, garante que a regra será executada para cada termo da expressão até que os índices **j** e **k** sejam iguais.

Outra maneira importante de testar seu código (como um iniciante) para encontrar o que está errado é o rastreio.

Bons Estudos!

Answer (score 3):

Erro resolvido. Deixo o código para ajudar quem possa estar com o mesmo problema.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main(){

    int tamanho, aux = 0;

    cout << "Qual o tamanho do vetor?  ";
    cin >> tamanho;

    float vetorA[tamanho], vetorB[tamanho];

    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++){  
        cout<< "Digite o numero :";     
        cin >> vetorA[i];
    }


    for(int i = 1; i <= tamanho; i++){
        aux = i + 1;
        for(int j = aux, k = 1; k <= i; j--, k++){
            vetorB[i-1] += j * vetorA[k-1];
        }       
    }   


    int c = 0;
    while(c < tamanho){
        cout << "\nA["<< c << "] = " << vetorA[c] << "\t B[" << c << "] = " << vetorB[c]; 
        c++; 
    }
}
```